# How to remove part of a string by condition - Python->Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the next DataFrame:

```
a = [{'name': 'AAA|YYY'},{ 'name': 'BBB|LLL'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)

      name
0  AAA|YYY
1  BBB|LLL
```

and I'm trying to remove the part of the string from the right up to the character `|`:

```
df['name'] = [i.split('|')[:-1] for i in df['name']]
```

but I get the following result:

```
    name
0  [AAA]
1  [BBB]
```

how can I get the following result?:

```
    name
0  AAA
1  BBB
```

Comment: have you tried removing the brackets in `df['name'] = [i.split('|')[:-1] for i in df['name']]` to look like `df['name'] = i.split('|')[:-1] for i in df['name']`

Comment: Hi, this won't work for pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting a range of items from the result of your split operation, because you're passing a slice object (`:-1`).

Actually, to get your result, you just have to select the first part of the split, which will correspond to the index `0`:

```py
df['name'] = [i.split('|')[0] for i in df['name']]
```

Or if you have multiple occurrences of `'|'`, and want to remove only the last part, you can join the remaining part after your selection:

```py
df['name'] = ['|'.join(i.split('|')[:-1]) for i in df['name']]
```